Update Release Agent Devops
I am using microsoft agent to build my pipeline and there are release agents installed on the app server. Pipeline -> Environment (for, QA, UAT, and PROD)
There is nothing in Org Setting -> Deployment Pools, it is empty. I see no option to update my agents. I am seeing a lot of vulnerabilities in _work folder in azagent on keyvault task with openssl.exe.
The reason I am looking for an option to update is I think that will help fix the vulnerabilities. How do I do it? Also, correct me if I am not going in the right direction.
I am not able to find a lot of details in documentation.
Please let me know if any additional details are required.

Note that there is a difference between a "Deployment Pool" and an "Agent Pool": agents in an Agent Pool are intended to compile and deploy anywhere; agents in a Deployment Pool are typically the deployment targets used in Classic Release pipelines. A good use case for Deployment Targets might be targeting a set of virtual machines in a scale set. Deployment Targets are created at the Project level but can be shared across DevOps Projects by creating a Deployment Pool at the organization level.
Although it's a bad practice, nothing prevents you from using an Agent Pool as a Deployment Target.
If you're not seeing agents in the Deployment pool, one possibility is that you don't have enough permissions to see it. The visibility of the pool is set to the Contributors of the Project that created it and Global Administrators. If you have sufficient permissions, confirm that you are not using a Agent Pool.
Also note that the Deployment Target is software components are added to the agent from the "tasks" that appear in the pipeline. If you see vulnerabilities related to the pipeline tasks, those vulnerabilities will reappear on the next pipeline execution. You may want to review the tasks that are used and determine if there are newer versions available.
As a general practice, I tend to avoid using agents on the target machines because they install additional tooling on the machine that will appear in security scans. If you're not using your Deployment Pool to perform a gradual rollout on a virtual machine scale set, you might be better off using something like SSH or PowerShell Remoting to remote into the box to apply changes to the machine.

Thanks for your response. Release agent are installed in respective environment app server. So when I go to Pipeline -> Environments I see 3, Q, U, P inside each under Resources have one VM (for each environment). The task I am using is AzureKeyVault@2 I think that is the latest task so I cannot event change that unfortunately
